# onLongClickListener issue

Tags: android, listview

This code is a partial code from my BaseAdapter which adapts my expandable listview.

This application is in general an Expandable ListView.

My goal is to set textview color to blue once the user has long clicked

in my listview's parent layout I got 2 strings , the holder is addressing them both.

I managed to set an onClickListener on the desired location and to set the desired function.
Thing is, now I need 2 functions to occur simultaneously:
When Long Clicked:
1. Copy to clipboard (the child's context)
2. paint the copied parent textview's row to a color to indicate that row was copied

Problem right now is I'm having trouble figuring out how to implement that.
I also know the code for setting the textview's bg color

"TextView".setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF5555"));
 "TextView".setHighlightColor(Color.BLUE);

etc..

thanks in advance for any response/help/assist , cheers.

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView rname_parent;
    TextView city_parent;
}

    @Override
public View getGroupView(int parent, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parentView) {
    Group group = (Group) getGroup(parent);
        ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_layout, parentView, false);
    //}

        //convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new LongClick(group.getName()));
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.rname_parent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rname_parent_layout);
        holder.city_parent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.city_parent_layout);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
     else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

        holder.rname_parent.setText(group.getName());
        holder.rname_parent.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
        holder.rname_parent.setTextSize(27);
        holder.city_parent.setText(group.getCity());

    return convertView;
}

//TODO ########################################################################
//TODO ##############this.content = The clipBoard String#######################
//TODO ########################################################################
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

    class  LongClick implements View.OnLongClickListener {
        private String content;
        public  LongClick (String content,String c2, String c3, String c4, String c5,String c6,String c7,String c8,String c9) {
            this.content = content+" "+c2+content;

        }

         // constructor used to obtain the item's valu
        @Override
        public  boolean  onLongClick (View  View){
            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)
                    View.getContext().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            // Scrapbook Manager
            clipboard.setText(content);

            // set the value of the scrapbook item of
            Toast mToast = Toast.makeText(View.getContext(), "Copy to the Clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            mToast.show();
            return  true ;
        }
    }


    //this method will return a view for each sub category

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int parent, int childPosition, boolean LastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parentView) {
        Child child = (Child) getChild(parent, childPosition);
        ArrayList<Child> ch = getAllchildren(parent);

        // if there is no current view for the specific child this will create it
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.child_layout, parentView,false);
        }
       convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new LongClick(ch.get(0).getName(), ch.get(1).getName(), ch.get(2).getName(), ch.get(3).getName(), ch.get(4).getName(), ch.get(5).getName(), ch.get(6).getName(), ch.get(7).getName(), ch.get(8).getName()));
/*
        convertView.isClickable();
        convertView.setLongClickable(true);
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        ArrayList<Child> ch = getAllchildren(parent);

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new LongClick(ch.get(0).getName(), ch.get(1).getName(), ch.get(2).getName(), ch.get(3).getName(), ch.get(4).getName(), ch.get(5).getName(), ch.get(6).getName(), ch.get(7).getName(), ch.get(8).getName());
        }
        //new LongClick(ch.get(0).getName(), ch.get(1).getName(), ch.get(2).getName(), ch.get(3).getName(), ch.get(4).getName(), ch.get(5).getName(), ch.get(6).getName(), ch.get(7).getName(), ch.get(8).getName())
        }
        );
        convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            ArrayList<Child> ch = getAllchildren(parent);
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                new LongClick(ch.get(0).getName(), ch.get(1).getName(), ch.get(2).getName(), ch.get(3).getName(), ch.get(4).getName(), ch.get(5).getName(), ch.get(6).getName(), ch.get(7).getName(), ch.get(8).getName());
                return true;
            }
        });
*/
        TextView child_textview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.child_txt);
        child_textview.setText(child.getName().toString());

        return convertView;
    }
```

Tried out TBridges's solution, added the implementation and the logcat error, clearly I'm doing some thing wrong, apparently I'm not addressing the OnLongClick view to the exact TextView :/

logcat message:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference
```

new implementation:

```
@Override
        public  boolean  onLongClick (View  View){
            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)
                    View.getContext().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            // Scrapbook Manager
            clipboard.setText(content);

            // set the value of the scrapbook item of
            Toast mToast = Toast.makeText(View.getContext(), "Copy to the Clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            mToast.show();
            //ViewHolder holder;
           // holder = new ViewHolder();
            //holder.rname_parent = (TextView) View.findViewById(R.id.rname_parent_layout);
            TextView tv = (TextView) View.findViewById(R.id.rname_parent_layout);
            if (View instanceof TextView) {
                tv = (TextView) View;
            }
            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF5555"));
            return  true ;
        }
    }
```

//Freaking me out

Answer (score 0):

In `onLongClick()` you should be able to do something like this:

```
Textview textView;
if (view instanceof TextView) {
    textView = (TextView) view;
}
// change text view's color
```

Comment: I've tried your approach, seems logically right.   how ever, it didnt work, added the implementation plus the logcat exception it gave , I'm surely doing something wrong :/

Comment: Okay, so it seems the View being passed in to onLongClick is not the TextView. Try using `view.findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId)`

Comment: I did mate, TextView tv = (TextView) View.findViewById(R.id.rname_parent_layout);

Comment: When long clicking the child I want the parent's textview background to change permanently, maybe the onclick listener is in the wrong place? since the parent's layout is in groupView